# root+chattr(Inappropriate ioctl for device while reading flags on ...)

Tags: linux, permissions

### lsattr file.txt

lsattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device while reading flags on file.txt

### chattr -i file.txt

chattr: Inappropriate ioctl for device while reading flags on file.txt

user: root

In what may be the problem? In the mount?

Answer (score 1):

Your filesystem does not support that kind of attributes.